# How to add spacing between links in borders

Tags: html

I am making a website and I have a border with links in it but the links don't have any spacing between them.

```html
  <h1><div style="background-color: #ADD8E6 ; padding: 30px; border: 2px solid black;"><a href="AboutUs.html"><font color="black"><strong>About Us</strong></font></a><a href="OurGames.html"><font color="black"><strong>Our Games</strong></font></a></h1>
```

Comment: FYI, the `font` tag has been deprecated for many, many years.

Answer (score 2):

use margin for `<a/>` it will works...

```css
a{
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<h1><div style="background-color: #ADD8E6 ; padding: 30px; border: 2px solid black;"><a href="AboutUs.html"><font color="black"><strong>About Us</strong></font></a><a href="OurGames.html"><font color="black"><strong>Our Games</strong></font></a></div></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a little typo and you have missed the closing **div** tag before the closing **h1** tag!

Answer (score 0):

Already you have got an answer, here I just removed the usage of font (deprecated) & strong tag:

```css
#styleMyDiv{
background-color: #ADD8E6 ;
padding: 30px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <div id="styleMyDiv">
    <a href="AboutUs.html" style="color: black;font-size: xx-large">About Us</a>
    <a href="OurGames.html" style="color: black;font-size: xx-large">Our Games</a>
  </div>
</h1>
```